# How to change button name from datetime-local

Tags: javascript, html

In mobile browsers datetime local has three buttons, One of the buttons' name is Set button, I want to change its name to Ok . Is it possible to do it ?
I searched but I couldn't find anything

```
 <input type="datetime-local"ng-model="task.Time">
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN's web site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local):

> The control's UI varies in general from browser to browser; at the moment support is patchy, with only Chrome/Opera and Edge on desktop — and most modern mobile browser versions — having usable implementations.

So, the answer is **no** - this element's UI is totally browser dependent and cannot be modified at this point.